# Is there a way to get Process id of unselected forground window in secondary screen

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

Windows Api consider the currently active/selected process as the only foreground process, I need to give focus to the application running in my other screen ( if the current process is active in primary screen, i want to focus the foreground application in the second screen and vice versa)

currently i can give selection to any process.

```
Process currentProcess  = Process.GetProcessById(2612);
var hWnd = currentProcess.MainWindowHandle;
if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
{
   SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
}
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Is there a way to find the process id of the application running in the other screen?

Comment: I don't understand. What unique identifying factor does the target process have?

Comment: it's the process running full screen (or taking the most part) on the second screen, this exactly my quesiton i don't know how to identify it, I know i can list all process but how i can find the desired process from this list there's only two way of filtering by id and by name.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Processes don't run on screens. A process can have multiple windows appearing on different monitors. It's a window you are looking for. Enumerate the windows and pick the one that matches your criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, actually i don't know what the criterias will be because i'm trying to build an app that gives focus to  windows based on the user's  face orientation, if the user turn his face to the second screen the software running in this screen get the focus.

Comment: Is there a way to find the process id based on screen coordinates ?

Comment: You should have a look at the [UI Automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-properties-for-clients). It's a bit easier to use than the windows API and can do things like find an element by position, see [AutomationElement.FromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.frompoint?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Automation_AutomationElement_FromPoint_System_Windows_Point_)

Comment: @MikeZboray That is perhaps overkill here, you can just enumerate all the windows and pick the biggest on the monitor you are interested in.

Comment: @Abdo **Is there a way to find the process id based on screen coordinates ?**get the window handle from the screen coordinates, then get the processid by the window handle, see my answer.

Comment: @AbdoDriowya: Why you need process id, if you need hwnd (for SetForegroundWindow) ?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that you believe that a pid and a window handle add the same thing

Comment: Maybe OP needs AllowSetForegroundWindow before SetForegroundWindow, but this is only my assumption...

Comment: thank you all for your answers, well if i can get the windows handle that's enough, with process i will extract the windows handle with 'MainWindowHandle'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to find the process id based on screen coordinates?

Yes. You can get the window handle from the coordinates(make sure the window is visible at the Point in your secondary screen) with [`WindowFromPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint). Then you can get both the processId and threadId associated with the handle by [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid)

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowFromPoint(Point),ref ProcessId);
```

Comment: Upvote, but I am lost what OP really need hwnd or pid? :-)

Comment: But why need pid? For SetForegroundWindow ?

Comment: Maybe he wants to terminate? or any other options in the following code? I think OP knows what he needs.

Comment: Sorry i wanted just the window handle but i was thinking that we can't get it without extracting it from the process.
so i will use WindowFromPoint(Point) with SetForegroundWindow
sorry to bother you i wasn't clear.

Comment: @AbdoDriowya np,It's a good learning experience for new guy. And then you will only need to call `WindowFromPoint` now.